# How do I delete a video in my Vimeo account?

Tags: c#, .net-core, vimeo, vimeo-api

How do I delete a video in my Vimeo account using the Vimeo API using C# in .Net Core?

Comment: If you have to add filler text, that means you are not writing a good question. Please take a look at the [help] and [ask].

Comment: Note that there is an [API Reference](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference) for the Vimeo API.

Comment: @john But it doesn't help you out if you are doing C# or .Net Core.

Comment: It makes perfect sense to me, as C# developer.

Comment: @John, some of us like examples. Such as myself.

Comment: It looks like there is a .NET API wrapper too ([linked here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/libraries)), although I admit that it doesn't seem to cover everything. It's probably a very good starting point though.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of how to structure your API requests in the Vimeo documentation, and there are also plenty of examples available on the internet of how to use HttpClient in C#. Any developer should be able to figure it out. StackOverflow isn't a copy/paste example repository.

Comment: @John without any examples. I've spent a lot of time searching for info to figure out this stuff. If you can get that obsolete wrapper to work, congratulations. If you look at the issues page for that wrapper you might think that maybe there is a reason I put this stuff up.

Comment: I'd hardly call something with a release as recent as Aug 27 obsolete.

Comment: It supports the v3 API, which is recent, and the code seems well written. I'm not sure why you're trashing *their* efforts. Did you even give the wrapper a try in all your research?

Comment: @Herohtar, yes, of course I gave it a try. .Net Core came out in 2016. Maybe I don't know how to read the dates but it seems like it was essentially completed before .Net Core came out. It doesn't target .Net Core. And while I don't know what the diff is between Vimeo API 3.0 and the current version of 3.4, which has been out who knows how long, there are more than a few changes since 3.0: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/changelog.

Comment: The project targets .NET Standard 2.0, which was the very latest until just last month when .NET Standard 2.1 was released. It has been targeting that version since January of this year, and has been using .NET Core in general since 2017 (initially targeting .NET Standard 1.3)

Comment: @Herohtar, OK, perhaps it is current. Even if it wasn't current, if I could make sense of it and used it to do something I would have been delighted. Clearly one or more people made very substantial contributions of time and effort to put that together. It looks like nice code and there is a lot of it. People like me benefit greatly from examples, which it lacked. Incidentally, the issues page included a request for examples of the most simple uses.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following works if you have a Vimeo account (at least it works at the Plus level and above) and have created an app, given that app permission to delete, gotten an access token for that app, and have a video number for the video you want to delete.

Within a class put the following code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();


    public async Task deleteVideo(string videoNumber, string accessToken) 
    {

        try
        {

            string vimeoApiUrl = "https://api.vimeo.com/videos/" + videoNumber; // Vimeo URL


            var body = "{}";

            HttpContent content = new StringContent(body);

            using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, vimeoApiUrl))
            {
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                requestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4");
                requestMessage.Headers.Add("ContentType", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                requestMessage.Content = content;
                var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            var errMessage = err.Message;
            Console.WriteLine("In deleteVideo() error: " + err.Message);
        }

    }
```

To call it from within that class:

```
await deleteVideo(videoNumber, accessToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```